# Unable to display Chinese chrcters in IOS app

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I am accessing following JSON from web service.

```
{"food":[{"mid":"1","name":" 首发"},{"mid":"2","name":"汤"},{"mid":"3","name":"沙拉"},{"mid":"4","name":"比萨"},{"mid":"5","name":"甜点"}]}
```

But it is displaying some numbers in app not the actual Chinese characters.

Please check my code; is anything wrong with it?

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"action=%@&appId=%@&langId=%@",@"menu",appId,langId];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURL];

NSLog(@"getMenu post : %@",post);
// Convert NSString to NSData format

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
// Create the URL Request and set the neccesary parameters

request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
//[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"getMenu responce=%@",returnString);

if ([returnString isEqualToString:@""])
{
    return nil;
}
else
{

NSError *e;

NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];;

return dataDict;

}
```

Comment: What encoding is the data you are receiving?

Comment: Thanks borrden  I am using collation utf8_unicode_ci  in db

Answer (score 1):

set one more property for NSMutableURLRequest object at the end

```
[request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Update your code from:

```
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

To

```
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mrunal I tried it with code  [request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; but it gives following error No visible @interface for 'NSMutableURLRequest' declares the selector 'setResponseEncoding:'

Comment: Thanks Mrunal I am directly using NSData returnData, I am not using returnString here, so any encoding will be applied to it its not used.